# error send email with phpmailer in server domain but succed in localhost

Tags: oop, phpmailer, php

i have detail error with this problem,

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-server.modulindo.com ESMTP Exim 4.77 #2 Wed, 11 Jul 2012 10:57:22 +0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-server.modulindo.com Hello mail.modulindo.com [202.67.9.42] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Reset OK

please help me guys!?

i have a problem with phpmailer. i send email with phpmailer in localhost is succeed, but when i upload it in my server domain, there was an error happend. the error is..

*SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.*

this is my script..

```
....
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "wasis85@gmail.com";

$mail->Password = "password"; 

$mail->From     = "wasis85@gmail.com";

$mail->FromName = "Wasis Lukito";

$mail->AddAddress($ema[$ari_no],"wasis");

$mail->AddCC("wasisl85@yahoo.com");

$mail->AddReplyTo("wasisl85@yahoo.com","Wasis Lukito");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  "Penolakan Data BPLPSE";

$mail->Body     =  "Alasan di tolak ";

$mail->AltBody  =  "This research is supported by Google.com";

...
```

Comment: @wasis for your safety consider mocking your gmail username and password ;) It is a valid one it seems :)

Answer (score 4):

i solved same problem with comment (or cancel) this line

//    $mail->IsSMTP();

this because from some server i had same error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate (also Password is incorrect...etc)

Comment: I tried this one but I'm still getting this error :
`SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)
The following From address failed: myemail@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,550,Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

SMTP server error: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)`

Comment: this solved my problem on netfirms.ca hosting provider. but it is taking time to arrive mail

Answer (score 0):

The script seems to be fine. I believe you have to check and make sure if your server supports SMTP or it has been properly configured for SMTP or not.

Comment: how to know my server support smtp or not?