# i configured PHP mailer api in it is working in localhost but not working on server. any solution

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpmailer

i configured windows server 2012 on amazon hosting EC2. I configured a PHP mailer api on localhost but when i deployed this application on server it do not working. Email can not send when i use it on online server. i allowed TCP 25 port on amazon Ec2 instance setting and also allowed inbound and outbound rule on firewall in window. why email is not sending?

Comment: What did you install on windows to send email? With windows you need to set up smtp settings as sendmail does not exist. You will run into issues sending directly from your ec2-instance as it is likely to get spam blocked. Look at using SES or another mail relay instead.

Comment: Please read one of the many duplicates of this question, and the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error send email with phpmailer in server domain but succed in localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410429/error-send-email-with-phpmailer-in-server-domain-but-succed-in-localhost)

Comment: when i configured phpmailer api for google email send successfully but when i try to send from third party email service it do not sending email ? that is real problem and when i try to send this code on localhost it successfully send email.

Comment: if it is impossible to send email through third party why it sending email through google ? @datasage

Comment: i am using third party email service of domainfactory  in ec2. it working nice on localhost but do not work on ec2

Answer (score 1):

As phpmailer page states:

> At the very least you will need class.phpmailer.php. If you're using SMTP, you'll need **class.smtp.php**, and if you're using POP-before SMTP, you'll need **class.pop3.php**.

So my guess here is you need to configure your smtp according to your server. I'll give you their example attached below for phpmailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                            // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```